# Load data from webservice while displaying splashscreen

Tags: iphone, web-services, splash-screen

I am trying to load some data from webservices while a splash screen is being displayed.

I am trying to use the code below for that, but I still can't reach a suitable solution.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [self backgroundtask];
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]]         autorelease];
    splashView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
    splashView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"];
    [self.window addSubview:splashView];
    [self.window bringSubviewToFront:splashView];

    ViewController *masterViewController = [[[ViewController alloc]         initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    self.navigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:masterViewController] autorelease];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

Comment: Whats wrong using above code ? Does it not work ? If there is a performance issue. Did you measure it using Instruments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display a splash screen just put an image file named "default.png" into the resources. The app will automatically display that at startup before any views load. And have in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` have the remainder of your code

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
 [self backgroundtask];
 self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]]         autorelease];


 ViewController *masterViewController = [[[ViewController alloc]         initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
 self.navigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:masterViewController] autorelease];
 self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
 [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

  self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]]         autorelease];
  //No need of splash View as u add Default.png to bundle and application will autimatically take it as Launch Image
  [self backgroundtask];
  ViewController *masterViewController = [[[ViewController alloc]         initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
  self.navigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:masterViewController] autorelease];
  self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```